# Erro de assinatura digital ao atualizar APK no Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, google-play

Ao migrar para o Android Studio, não deu certo a importação do meu antigo projeto. Sendo assim, e por não ser um app muito complexo, eu criei outro com o mesmo pacote e exportei usando a mesma keystore, mas ao tentar upar o APK eu recebo essa mensagem:

[image: Erro]

Pesquisei sobre e não encontrei solução, e no console do Google Play as opções de ajuda são muito restritas e categorizadas, e a única coisa que tem a dizer sobre isso é que os apps devem ser gerados pela mesma keystore e ter o mesmo pacote, e isso eu já estou fazendo.

Criar outro app no Play me será muito custoso. Primeiro porque eu tenho mais de um app com essa keystore e vou ter que excluir e enviar outros novos para cada um. Também não quero de jeito algum perder as estatisticas de download e classificação dos apps, além de haver ID's como o do Admob, Crashlytics, Facebook sdk, por exemplo relacionados a eles.

**UPDATE**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom, uma coisa é certa: o sistema não se enganaria em relação à *keystore* utilizada, então você precisa verificar de fato se esta última é realmente a que foi utilizada na versão anterior. Com [este comando](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/1216394) você consegue visualizar a impressão SHA1 do seu certificado. Compare com o do erro da loja.

Comment: Matheus, poderia também colocar como você está assinando o apk? Usando via linha de comando usando o `jarsigner` ou pela IDE (Gerar APK...)?

Comment: Wakim, eu estou exportando usando o menu do Android Studio mesmo.
Paulo, eu sempre tive apenas uma keystore. Assim que puder eu faço essa verificação, agora não da pq estou no trabalho.
Eu acho que isso tem mais ver com o fato de eu ter começado outro projeto do zero, apesar de ter o mesmo pacote e a mesma keystore. Mas eu não tive outra escolha.
Obrigado.

Comment: Atualizei la em cima...

Comment: A *keystore* que você deve verificar não é a de *debug*, pois não é com ela que você assina seus aplicativos para enviar para a Play Store. Você tem uma de produção, não?

Comment: Já atualizei a pergunta novamente.
Na verdade eu já tinha feito isso antes, mas como deu esse erro que o arquivo não existe, eu achei que tinha que ser feito na key debug. Não sei o que fazer...